# IBM Cloud Function OpenWhisk node.js calling WIOTP over http

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-iot, openwhisk

I am trying to use https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/openwhisk-package-watsoniotp in an OpenWhisk sequence (containing two actions) all code is node.js

Testing the sequence using Postman. Once the action completes, the action returns the variable, `payload`. The variable `payload` is passed over to the next action in the sequence which is the openwhisk-package-watsoniotp (added via a binding in the IBM Cloud console so I am unable to modify this code, it is locked).

I can post data from postman into Watson IoT platform via the sequence. However the format of the payload is interpreted as a String, not a JSON string.

This is the body I post from Postman, one of the variants I have tried.

`{"payload": "{'speed': 10}"}`

My node.JS actions return the input, unmodified.

`return {payload: params.payload};`

The value should be a JSON string. However WIOTP is unable to interpret the payload and basically tokenizes the values. This is evident when I try to create a board and a card. The property list lets me select each value in the array.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZbRf.png)

The openwhisk-package-watsontiotp code as far as I can tell just takes, `params.payload` as is and passes it along.

Answer (score 1):

I found an example in the code that answer the question,

The payload, should be nested. I missed that originally.

```
{
    "key": "sampleInput",
        "value": {
        "eventType": "status",
            "payload": {
            "temp": 4
        },
        "domain": "messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com",
            "typeId": "xxxx",
                "deviceId": "xxxx01"
    }
}
```